# Resulting slurry characteristics of mixing slurries of different densities in an overflowing reactor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, mass, conservation-laws, density

Given a *continuously overflowing reactor* of $T \; hr$ residence time, a slurry of known varying flow-rate and varying density is introduced. How do we calculate the resulting density at outlet?

I was thinking of computing the total content of slurry accumulating in $T \; hr$, similar to a simple moving average or should I use a more complex model such as the ideal continuously stirred tank reactor?

Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the writer of this post has no prior background or knowledge in reactor flow analysis. However, the following answer provides a simplistic model for analysis.

Let $0 < \tilde{V}$ be the volume of the reactor, let $Q(t) := \frac{\text{volume}}{\text{time}}$ denote the flow-rate, $\rho(t)$ be the time-varying density of the slurry, $m(t)$ be the mass contained by the reactor at time $0 < t$ and $T \; hr$ be the retention or residence time of the slurry introduced in the reactor. Then the conservation of mass implies $0 = \frac{d}{dt}\text{m}(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \int_\tilde{V} \rho d v \approx \rho_{in}(t) Q_{in}(t) - \rho_{out}(t) Q_{out}(t)$ which can be approximated by a simplistic lumped-mass model as $(\rho_{in}(t) Q_{in}(t) - \rho_{out}(t) Q_{out}(t)) \cdot T \approx \frac{\rho_{in}(t) + \rho_{out}(t)}{2} \cdot \tilde{V}$. The final equation can then be used to compute $\rho_{in}(t)$ if $\rho_{in}(t)$ is known.

---

*Edit*

Assuming that $T$ is the [mean residence time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_time#Mean_age_and_mean_residence_time), $E(\tau) = \frac{\exp(-\frac{\tau}{T})}{T}$ is the ideal residence time or exit age distribution. This is an exponential distribution with mean $T$ and variance $1$. Further $\tau = 
\frac{C_{in} - C_{out}}{-r}$ where $C_{in}$, $C_{out}$ and $r$ are the concentrations at the inlet and outlet and the reaction rate respectively. If the relationship of the concentration to the density and flow-rate is known, then the previous equation can be used to calculate the outlet density.

Comment: Thanks kb314, shouldn't we have expected some exponential term in the solution because the outlet density would have less variability than the inlet density due to the residence time?

Comment: @Vinlar, I have edited the answer to reflect my brief reading of the exponential distribution of the idea continuously flowing stirred reactor (CSTR).